# Нажатие кнопки на сайте(не своём) через Java

Tags: javascript, java

Есть сайт, нужно, чтобы при запуске программы  нажималась кнопка на сайте. Сайт не должен открываться в браузере.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser#List_of_headless_browsers) и скрипт для него, эмулирующий действия пользователя. Я бы предпочёл [PhantomJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhantomJS). Пример реализации клика можно найти, например, [тут](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/phantomjs/phantomjs_examples.htm)

Comment: Всё-таки Chrome Headless лучше фантома.

Comment: @ПавелВороник, не нужно открывать в браузере, в итоге нужно скачать браузер и открыть сайт, логика на высшем уровне прямо! =) Тогда проще будет использовать `SeleniumWebDriver` и `chromedriver`. Тут хоть профили можно настраивать с историей и куками, юзверьагентами.